# linux netlink struct member definition

Tags: linux, c

I recently came across this while browsing the Linux kernel source:

```
struct netlink_kernel_cfg cfg = {
    .input  = scsi_nl_rcv_msg,
    .groups = SCSI_NL_GRP_CNT,
};
```

The full source is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_netlink.c#L128).

I am trying to understand how the member definitions `.input` and `.groups` work? The C `struct`s I am familiar with are similar to:

```
struct employee{
       char    name[30];
       int     empId;
       float   salary;
};
```

So how do `.input` and `.groups` work?

Comment: Those are c99 [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). You will initialize your struct as `struct employee foo = { .salary = -.001, .name = "bar", .empId = 1334 };`

Comment: @mosvy Things are starting to become very clear to me now. Thank you very much for the clarification and example What is the benefit or advantage of doing things this way using designated initialization compared to the normal way ? And how do I select your comment as the correct answer though ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) said in a comment, these are [C99 designated initialisers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

```c
struct netlink_kernel_cfg cfg = {
    .input  = scsi_nl_rcv_msg,
    .groups = SCSI_NL_GRP_CNT,
};
```

doesn’t declare a structure (as your `employee` example does), it declares a variable, `cfg`, of type `struct netlink_kernel_cfg`, and initialises two of its members, `input` and `groups`.

The main advantages of this syntax are that the declaration order no longer matters, that members can be omitted (and are initialised in the same way as static variables), and that it’s easier to read.